# Unable to send email to Verizon addresses. All other addresses fine

Tags: linux, email

One of the users on my server (96.31.68.20) is having trouble sending email to any Verizon accounts. It looks like my server has been blacklisted by them for some reason. The message in the email is:

> *yAAAn@verizon...net
>       SMTP error from remote mail server after initial connection:
>       host relay.verizon.net [206.46.232.11]: 571 Email from
>   96.31.68.20 is currently blocked by Verizon Online's anti-spam system. The
>   email sender or Email Service Provider
>   may
>   visithttp://www.verizon.net/whitelist
>   and request removal of the block.
>   110510*

There's no unusual levels of mail activity coming from my server, and I've checked all the blacklist sites and the IP does not appear there.

I used the online white request on Verizon's site, and I got this message:

> After investigation, Verizon Online
>   Security has determined that e-mail
>   from your IP address will not be
>   allowed access to the Verizon Online
>   e-mail domain due to one or more of
>   the following reasons:
>
> Your IP has been blocked because of
>   spam issues or because your ISP
>   indicates that it is dynamically
>   assigned
>
> No Reverse Hostname associated with
>   your IP address.

As far as I can see this is rubbish... or am I looking in the wrong places?

What other information do I need to be able to diagnose this?

I'm happy to make changes if necessary, but I've no idea where to go next.

Help!

EDIT: Might be worth noting that I've tried the removal request 4 times over two months. Same result each time.

Comment: Looks like you do in fact have a reverse lookup hostname on that IP; was that added after they rejected your request?

Comment: Nope, been there since server setup!

Comment: I see you do have a reverse lookup, you may be blacklisted somewhere you haven't checked yet.

Comment: Well, if there aren't any spam issues, then I think all of their reasons are out the window; the reverse lookup is fine and that [IP range is clearly a hosting company](http://whois.arin.net/rest/net/NET-96-31-64-0-1/pft).  An SPF record is the only thing I'd suggest adding, but they didn't mention that as a reason..  Is there any way you can tell them, "you're wrong, look again"?

Comment: @SpacemanSpiff I'd love to find someone that I'm listed, I really would. At least I could diagnose if so. I'll take another look around.

Comment: @ShaneMadden Thanks for your input. Not sure how I'd do that. There don't seem to be any contacts listed. The email basically says: "sort out your issue and use this form again when you're done". Endless Loop.

Comment: I'd say throw up an SPF record (see [here](http://www.openspf.org/Introduction)) so you can check that box on the form, and send it again; may get a different result.

Comment: I'm digging for a link I used to have that searched a good majority of your blacklists at once.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I'll try the SPF record.  I used this tool: [link](http://www.mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx) and it's all greens. Are there likely to be any others worth checking?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this?  I'm having the same problem.  I'm clean on several large, aggregate blacklist checks (including mxtoolbox); rDNS is correct; IP is static and is not shared; SPF record is in place; I've thorougly tested as not being an open relay.  Despite that, Verizon claims "No Reverse Hostname associated with your IP address" which is obviously incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Try http://mxtoolbox.com/blacklists.aspx.

It seems it might be coming down to maybe two possibilities:

- You are on an IP block that is identified as dynamic-allocatable (via a list Verizon is utilizing)
- Your hosting outfit is hosting someone else who is a spammer

Did you know that "female-genital-warts.com" is sharing your IP?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue.  As I mentioned in my comment, I was clean on several large, aggregate blacklist checks (including mxtoolbox and some more comprehensive ones); rDNS was correct; IP was static and was not shared; SPF record was in place; and I'd thoroughly tested as not being an open relay. Despite that, when I used their automated whitelist service, Verizon claimed `No Reverse Hostname associated with your IP address` which was obviously incorrect.

Therefore I sent an email to their whitelist support address.  I won't list it here for obvious reasons, but it's in the information provided at the URL pointed to in the SMTP rejection.  I explained all the points I made in my first paragraph.

About a week later, I received a response:

> Thank you for contacting Verizon Online Abuse. After a thorough investigation of your issue, Verizon Online Abuse has determined that normal e-mail delivery should be restored within 2 hours.

I resubmitted the queued emails and they went through fine.  I haven't had a problem with them since.

Comment: Upvoted for providing the obvious answer: Contact Verizon.

Answer (score 0):

The [thread on verizon support forum](http://businessforums.verizon.net/t5/Verizon-net-Email/Impossible-to-Whitelist-IP-Domain/td-p/525791) lists necessary steps to open ticket with verizon on this. You need to be verizon customer in some way to be able to post on the forum though.